# Don't working Centos7 root password recovery methods

Tags: centos, password, initramfs

Each time whenever I tried to get in initrd shell i was faced with the same problem "Starting switch boot" and it did nothing... I tried to put `rw init=/bin/sh` instead of `ro` in kernel boot params, then i tried `rw init=/sysroot/bin/sh` instead of `ro`, then i tried `systemd.unit=emergency.target systemd.unit=rescue.target` but it also gave no results...SELinux status is Permissive, `CentOS Linux release 7.8.2003 (Core)`. What else can i check?

I noticed that RHEL doc page recieved the 404 error
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/sec-terminal_menu_editing_during_boot#sec-Changing_and_Resetting_the_Root_Password

UPD: sorry, i didn't mention `rd.break` also doesn't work for me :(

[image]

Comment: When you say all those things you tried gave no results, what do you mean?  What happened?

Answer (score 2):

I wrote an article about it is in Polish, but it has images, so with the images and instructions below, you should be able to get it working.

Link to article: https://pl.euro-linux.com/blog/resetowanie-hasla-roota/

Now instructions, that are a little bit different, that one proposed already:

1. on boot menu, press `e` button to edit kernel parameters.
2. Move cursor (with arrows) to end of kernel line (linux16) it would look then like this: `linux16 /vmlinuz(...) rd.break`, there is space between last parameter and `rd.break`.
3. `mount -o rw,remount /sysroot`
4. `chroot /sysroot`
5. `passwd` - change password
6. `load_policy -i` - IF it fails, move to point 8
7. `restorecon -Rv /etc/` - only if 6 worked
8. `touch /.autorelabel` - ONLY IF 6 failed! relabel on big machines is VERY SLOW!
9. `exit` && `reboot` - or any other way to restart machine.

If it doesn't work, please attach additional images, information so I could edit that answer to the point that it works for you.

Comment: You forgot the chroot after step 3

Comment: @jsbillings thanks! Fixed

Comment: +1 for this -- the only answer I've found after an hour which says to `load_policy -i` so that SELinux is enabled inside the chroot!  Thanks